# Set height of inline box dynamically to same value as width

Tags: html, css

For some numbers in a text, I want give them an appearance of coins.
This seems pretty easy at first: put them in a span background and apply some `border-radius`.

But how can I achieve a quadratic box (to get a circle with `border-radius`)?

First I tried `display: inline flow-root` to have a block formatting context and be able to set height with `aspect-ratio: 1/1`.

But with this the box grows only to bottom. How do I center the box, but let its content stay on the normal text line? `vertical-align: middle` would center the box, but moves content too, so coin number wouldn't stay at the baseline with the surrounding text.

And furthermore in block formatting context coin box with three digit numbers will push the lines apart.

Is there a solution to get a quadratic box for inline elements, which don't push lines apart? (it is okay if the box overlap the surrounding lines a bit)

```css
.coinDukat {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 0.2em;
    min-width: 1.1em;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    background: goldenrod;
    color: #815d05;
    text-align: center;
/*vertical-align: middle;*/
}
```

```html
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, ipsum dolor sit sadipscing elitr, ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, <span class="coinDukat">1</span> sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sit Preis: <span class="coinDukat">300</span>. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt <span class="coinDukat">50</span> magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remembered the pattern with a absolute positioned `::before` pseudo element:
In addition this works with an image for background (in my case a circular metal texture)

```css
.coinDukat {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-inline-start: 0.15em;
  padding-inline-end: 0.15em;
}
.coinDukat:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: yellow;
  //background-image: url("../images/Dukat.avif");
  //background-position: center;
  //background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, ipsum dolor sit sadipscing elitr, ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, <span class="coinDukat">1</span> sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sit Preis: <span class="coinDukat">300</span>. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt <span class="coinDukat">50</span> magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```

But does anybody know, why i need to set z-index on the span?

Comment: You don’t seem to have circles.

Answer (score 1):

I would fake this with some `clip-path` and an overflowing background.

The border is used to create the overflowing background: https://css-tip.com/overflowing-background/

```css
.coinDukat {
  padding: .2em; /* space inside the circle */
  margin: .2em; /* space outside the circle */
  border-image: linear-gradient(goldenrod 0 0) fill 0//100vw; /* the color here (don't need to touch the other values) */
  clip-path: circle(71%); /* make a circle that fit the content */
  color: #815d05;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, ipsum dolor sit sadipscing elitr, ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, <span class="coinDukat">1</span> sed diam nonumy eirmod
  tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sit Preis: <span class="coinDukat">300</span>. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt <span class="coinDukat">50</span> magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
  eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```

Related question to understand the `71%` of the `clip-path`: [clip-path:circle() radius doesn't seem to be calculated correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59779083/8620333)